# How to do user authentication in django when using windows (crypt module is not supported on windows)

Tags: python, django

I was trying to register user in django using User model from 'django.contrib.auth.models', but when encrypting password, it shows 'The crypt module is not supported on Windows'. Also I tried importing from passlib.hash  the pbkdf2_sha256 to encrypt the data.

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email')

class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'password']
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        encryptedpass = pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt(validated_data['password'], rounds=12000, salt_size=32)
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=validated_data['username'], email=validated_data['email'], password=encryptedpass)
        
        return user
```

views.py

```
class RegisterAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
            })
class LoginAPI(KnoxLoginView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        encryptedpass = pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt(request.data['password'], rounds=12000, salt_size=32)
        mydata = {'username':request.data['username'], 'password':encryptedpass}
        serializer = AuthTokenSerializer(data=mydata)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        login(request, user)
        return super(LoginAPI, self).post(request, format=None)

# Get User API
class UserAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated,]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

But during authentication in login part, it does not match the credentials, maybe because the function checking for validity uses some other encryption method. How to solve this issue.

Comment: I think you are using the default `AuthtokenSerializer` but you are using your own password hashing method. Maybe you need to follow the proper hashing technique of Django. Here is [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/passwords/) for the same.

Comment: Or you can use `make_password()` method of Django. here is the [make_password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.make_password)